# How to export Html formatted string as Excel file (.xlsx) format in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, excel

I have Report contains Html Table with custom formatting. When I am trying to export it in Excel format (.xlsx) using Stream Writer which is converted and when try to open it gives an error that "File has been corrupted or file format does not support this format".

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: XSLX is a completely different format than HTML. You can't just naively stream one into the other. Excel _can_ open HTML files if they're just plain text containing HTML markup, but that's not the same as the native XLSX format. So either just save the file as HTML and then use Excel to open it, or find a library (there are some free ones) which can write data into the native Excel format and create your file that way.

Comment: @Adyson Thanks for the reply. I get some 3rd party library like SpireXML free library. I will try it.